# Simplify this logic set

Tags: logic

I need to simplify the following set **$[(A' \cup B') \cup C]' \cup [(B \cap C')' \cap A]$**

using algebraic properties. Is there anywhere where I can check the steps and the final answer? anyone can help me to simplify it? thanks.

Thanks

Comment: The answer should be $A$.

Comment: Thanks samjoe. Do you have the steps to check if I'm doing it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$[(A' \cup B') \cup C]' \cup [(B \cap C')' \cap A] =$$

$$[A' \cup B' \cup C]' \cup [(B \cap C')' \cap A] =$$

$$[A \cap B \cap C'] \cup [(B \cap C')' \cap A] =$$

$$A \cap [(B \cap C') \cup (B \cap C')'] =$$

$$A \cap U =$$

$$A$$

Answer (score 0):

Having these symbology: $+$: Union, $\cdot$: Intersection, $'$ Complement, $1$: True (tautology), $0$: False (contradiction):

$$
((A'+B')+C)'+(BC')'A \text{}\\
=(A'+B')'C'+(B'+C)A\\
=ABC'+(B'+C)A\\
=ABC'+B'A+CA\\
=ABC'+AB'+AC\\
=ABC'+AB'(C+C')+AC\\
=ABC'+AB'C+AB'C'+AC\\
=ABC'+AB'C'+AB'C+AC\\
=A(B+B')C'+AB'C+AC\\
=AC'+AC+AB'C\\
=A+AB'C\\
=A
$$